# Function that autoincrements whenever it is called in R

Tags: r, function

In R, is it possible to have a function that autoincrements and returns a value before incrementing whenever it is called?

```
t_i=1
autoincrement=function(){
    temp=t_i
    t_i=t_i+1
    return(temp)
}
#this however does not modify t_i globally, only locally.
```

intended outcome:

```
>autoincrement()
1

>autoincrement()
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<<-` where *the operator `<<-` cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned.*

```
t_i=1
autoincrement=function(){
    temp=t_i
    t_i <<- t_i+1
    return(temp)
}
autoincrement()
#[1] 1
autoincrement()
#[1] 2
```